# How to check that an element belongs to a stabilizer group?

Tags: group-theory, quantum-computer, quantum-error-correction

## My direct Question:

For a given stabilizer $S=\langle g_1,...,g_n\rangle$ (only represented by the generator) and an operator $g$, how can we check that $g\in S$? A wrong answer is to check that "if $g$ is independent of $S$ by using check-matrix", as mentioned in Nielsen's book. This is because of that the phase information in the check-matrix is missing. Therefore it cannot distinguish $g$ and $-g$.

## Why I want to do this

Following Nielsen's book (for learning), I want to build a stabilizer simulator that can be simulated fast in a classical PC. In the section "10.5.3 Measurement in the stabilizer formalism", when the measurement $g$ is commuted with $S$, we need to check exactly whether $g$ or $-g$ is in $S$.

Answer (score 0):

After struggling for a whole day, I find a way out, though in a less smart way. The point is still to find the linear expansion. Since we know $g$ or $-g$ must be a stabilizer. We assume that $\lambda g$ is the stabilizer and we want to determine $\lambda$.
We know that $\lambda g = \prod_i g_i^{\lambda_i} $, where ${\lambda_i}$ is either 0 or 1 (since $g_i^2=1$). Therefore we have

$r(\lambda g)=r(g)=\sum_i \lambda_i r(g_i)$.

Then we can solve the equation $Ax=b$, where $A=S^T$, $b=r^T(g)$ and $x^T=(\lambda_1,..,\lambda_n)$. After we obtaining $\{\lambda_i\}$, we can calculate $g'=\prod_i g_i^{\lambda_i}$. Then by comparing $g'$ and $\lambda g$ we can obtain $\lambda$.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).